# Can I export an NFS share with faked root privileges

Tags: linux, permissions, users, nfs

I'm writing software for an embedded linux system and I'm using an NFS share as root directory. The root filesystem resides in `/srv/nfs/rootfs`, and it is exported using the following `/etc/exports`:

```
/srv/nfs *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,async,wdelay)
```

The content of `/srv/nfs/rootfs` need to be owned by root, otherwise the target system will have trouble mounting `/dev`. However, I need to be able to modify the files in `/srv/nfs/rootfs` as regular user, and I don't want to add `sudo` to my scripts or run sudo on every other command. Is there some way of configuring NFS to fake root privileges on `/srv/nfs/rootfs`? I was thinking of trying to run nfs using fakeroot, but that does not seem like the best solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ACLs on `/srv/nfs/rootfs` to give additional user(s) write access - see `man setfacl` / `man getfacl` for more info. If you decide to go this way, using the default ACLs might be a good idea - this would ensure, that the ACLs set for directories get propagated on file/directory creation. Yet there is a catch: the newly created files will be owned by the user creating them. Hence you might want to run `chown root:` periodically on your NFS export or hook something to FAM (File Alteration Monitor, e.g. `gamin`).

As a side note: exporting **writable** things **world-wide** (`/srv/nfs *(rw,...`) is almost never a good idea, no matter how much one thinks his/her environment is isolated from the rest of the universe.